# How to awaken a controller before using it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Situation

I have an ionic side menu app with a main controller 'main view'. Each tab has it's own controller, child of the main ctrl. When I'm starting the app, the first controller starts and shows datas coming from a Firebase DB in the 'main view'. My problem is, my tab 'customer' is not fill up with DB datas before I click to go in...

## The problem

...But the behaviour is really strange, because when I'm clicking on this tab 'customer', no informations from DB are showed, to load datas I need to click on the side menu, it appears, and just at this moment my datas are loaded in my tab ! But before, I get an empty view... The funny fact is sometimes, once on ten times it works : my page is correctly load !

## What I've tried

From my point of view, my 'customer' controller seems asleep when my 'main view' is loaded, so I tried different way to "awaken" it before click on its tab page.

I tried to broadcast a "start" signal from my main controller, and catch it in my 'customer' controller on a $scope.$on function, but it didn't work.

Also tried a `$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams)`, it works for the back button, but not to load the view when the app is started.

Even when I change the previous `$on` function, into `$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function()`, same results.

The problem could came from the way I'm loading datas in the 'customer' tab, because it's a firebase call, so maybe a synchronous request problem ?

## What I want to do

What I'm trying to achieve is, when my app is started either all controllers are loaded (but will this fix the synchronous request problems ?) or simply have a normal behaviour when I'm clicking on the tab. Click = normal datas loading in the 'customer' tab DOM.

```js
// Customer controller

function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebase, $firebaseArray, $state, $ionicPopup, $location) 
{

$scope.getCustomer = function()
{  
    $scope.listCustomer = "";
    $scope.newCustomer = []; 

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var refCustomer = firebase.database().ref("customers/"+user.uid+"/orders/");
    $scope.orderTmp = $firebaseArray(refCustomer);

        $scope.chatTmp.$loaded().then(function()
        {
                angular.forEach($scope.orderTmp, function(order) 
                {
                    var refOrderHist = firebase.database().ref("History/"+order.$id);
                    
                    refOrderHist.once('value').then(function(snapshot)
                    {
                        if(snapshot.val() === null)
                        {
                            refOrderHist.child(order.$id).remove();
                            refCustomer.child(order.$id).remove();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                   $scope.newCustomer.push(snapshot.val());
                        }
            
                    });
                });
        });
        $scope.listCustomer = $scope.newCustomer;
};

// I'm usigin this $on for the back button
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    if ($location.path() === "/side-menu/customer") {
  $scope.getCustomer();
    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

suggest you can use ng-init in customer view root element and bind it to method named like "viewLoad" and inside viewLoad method load data using http service.

move this line after forech inside then callback function

```
 $scope.listCustomer = $scope.newCustomer;
```

does $scope.chatTmp.$loaded() use $http service inside? because $http service callback trigger digest cycle, if it use other ajax API like jquery ajax API, then you must call $scope.$apply by your self inside success callback.

Comment: So the "viewLoad" function should be in the customer controller, right ? I never used before the http service, what it can exactly do in my case, load a specific adresse ?

Comment: yes and about your second question read this page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: The problem with "ng-init" is, it runs the "viewLoad" function, but because the DOM was previously loaded, I still can't see the bound datas in my view. Is there a way to run the "ng-init" function before the DOM binding ? Or maybe a way to load in the cache my "customer" controller from the main one ?